# slurm sbatch queues tasks but nothing executes

Tags: bash, slurm

I'm using slurm on an AWS cluster and have written a script for execution that doesn't seem to work. If I run the script by itself, it runs fine. However, when run with `sbatch` it doesn't work.

I call `sbatch` with the following code:

```
for sample in `cat url.txt`;
    do sudo /opt/slurm/bin/sbatch ./slurm_script.sh $sample; 
    sleep 1;
done
```

The script `slurm_script.sh` contains a very long bioinformatics pipeline. It does work when called on its own [`bash slurm_script.sh someString`]

It outputs onto the master node:

```
Submitted batch job 2
Submitted batch job 3
Submitted batch job 4
Submitted batch job 5
...
```

but when I ssh into any compute node, there are no processes running. No files are created either. Any ideas?

Comment: What the error logs say? If the jobs didn't created any, what the SLURM error log says? And why are you running sbatch under sudo?

Comment: Can you execute "squeue"?

Comment: @Poshi I'm running sbatch under sudo because we need permissions to write to a specific folder during the script. If I run `sudo bash slurm_script.sh` everything is good, but if I run `bash slurm_script.sh`, it fails. Where can I find the SLURM error logs?

Comment: @BubEspinja running squeue reveals `(ReqNodeNotAvail, UnavailableNodes:dummy-compute)` for every queued job.

Comment: So here you are: a node with that fulfills your requirements is not available (probably does not exists). What did you requested?

Comment: hmmm...there are 22 nodes of type r4.xlarge. But they are all idle.

Comment: What did you requested? And what an r4.xlarge node have?

Comment: @Poshi r4.xlarge is 4 CPUs and 30.5 GB ram. I haven't requested anything outside the code above. I'm not sure what `requested node not available` means.

Comment: In the code above the sbatch parameters does not appear. If you are using entirely default values, you should see which are them.

Comment: You can use `scontrol show job $jobid` to query about the actual parameters of your jobs. Check them against the resources available. If something like 5 cpus are requested and your nodes have only 4, the "requested node not available" will appear. So check all resources: cpu, memory, disk...

Comment: @Poshi Thanks. Figured it out with your commands. Since this is my first time using slurm, how does one check on the process completion status? I have print statements in the script, but obviously that doesn't work unless running like `bash scriptname.sh`.

Comment: After the job execution, you can check the stats and status with the `sacct` command. Check the overall SLURM documentation, these are the basic commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to figure this out, but slurm's error and out directories were not created in the proper folder prior to running the script. I created these directories in ~/slurm_out and ~/slurm_error. However, after running the following under suggestion @Poshi

```
scontrol show job
```

I saw that slurm was looking for these in the following directories:

```
...
WorkDir=/scratch/missing
StdErr=/scratch/missing/slurm_error/error_85.txt
StdIn=/dev/null
StdOut=/scratch/missing/slurm_out/output_85.txt
Power=
...
```

After creating `slurm_error` and `slurm_out` in the directory where slurm was looking, the script began running!

Comment: You know you can change the working dir, the error file and output file, right? Check the `sbatch` parameters.